# problema al hacer impresion a un reporte en ireport

Tags: java, sql, ireport

hola colegas lo que sucede es que cuando hago el preview de mi reporte utilizando el jar ireport, lo carga bien osea aparece en la posición que deseo, asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, al momento de mandarlo a imprimir, termina asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna propiedad que no este viendo? necesito consejos ya que hasta ahora no logro encajarlo donde deseo. Saludos y gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.

Comment: y cual es el error? , no entiendo , la impresión sale bien. Si te lo imprime de otro color, la impresora también tiene que ver , ya que la gama de colores es distinta a la del pc

Comment: hola! el error es que al mandar a imprimir el reporte, el recuadro se imprimir a la mitad de la hoja. ese es el error ya que inicialmente en el preview aparece al inicio de la hoja, mira en la imagen. :(

Comment: Agrega el código donde llenas el reporte y donde lo imprimes, para poder ver que es lo que estás haciendo.

Comment: @kevin ramirez soto revisa que datos generales y datos vacantes estén cada uno en un detalle o detail